# "No Message " Imap Laravel error while fetching emails from outlook account?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, imap, laravel-6

I am trying to fetch an email from outlook Inbox with the Imap package of Laravel. it is working fine with Gmail. but when I try to fetch emails from outlook it gives No message error
`ImapController.php`

```
 */
    public function index()
    {
        // dd(phpinfo());
        // imap_open('{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX', 'info@coldxpress.com.au', 'Dac67132');
        $oClient = Client::account('default');
        $oClient->connect();

        //Get all Mailboxes
        /** @var \Webklex\IMAP\Support\FolderCollection $aFolder */
        $aFolder = $oClient->getFolders('INBOX.Sent');

        //Loop through every Mailbox
        /** @var \Webklex\IMAP\Folder $oFolder */
        foreach ($aFolder as $oFolder) {

            //Get all Messages of the current Mailbox $oFolder
            /** @var \Webklex\IMAP\Support\MessageCollection $aMessage */
            $aMessage = $oFolder->messages()->since('10.02.2020')->get();

            /** @var \Webklex\IMAP\Message $oMessage */
            foreach ($aMessage as $oMessage) {
                echo $oMessage->getSubject() . '<br />';
                // echo 'Attachments: ' . $oMessage->getAttachments()->count() . '<br />';
                // echo $oMessage->getHTMLBody(true);
            }
        }

        // return view('home');
    }
```

`Config/imap.php`

```
    'accounts' => [

        'default' => [// account identifier
            'host'  => env('IMAP_HOST', 'outlook.office365.com'),
            'port'  => env('IMAP_PORT', 993),
            'protocol'  => env('IMAP_PROTOCOL', 'imap'), //might also use imap, [pop3 or nntp (untested)]
            'encryption'    => env('IMAP_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'), // Supported: false, 'ssl', 'tls', 'notls', 'starttls'
            'validate_cert' => env('IMAP_VALIDATE_CERT', false),
            'username' => env('IMAP_USERNAME', 'info@coldxpress.com.au'),
            'password' => env('IMAP_PASSWORD', '*********'),
        ],
```

I want to fetch Emails from Outlook account.

Comment: Is 10.02.2020 really the right date syntax? Might want to check that.